# PayPal Express (checkout.js): Disable enter key

Tags: javascript, paypal

When a user presses the enter key on my site the PayPal Express modal pops up. I need to prevent this happening. 
I am using client-side PayPal Express (checkout.js).

I have tried `$("#paypal-button").blur()`

What I need is a way to prevent the box popping up, by setting a JavaScript variable (some way to validate).

```
  payment: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: 35, currency: 'USD' }, description: name + " " + email, custom: 'New York'
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Comment: It sounds like the paypal express button is in focus, removing that should prevent the enter button triggering the event.

Comment: I try that and the problem persists.

Comment: What I need is a way to validate the payment. So that when a javascript variable is set a certain way the box does not trigger when the user presses enter.

Comment: Show the HTML, too.

Comment: The only HTML is <div id="paypal-button"></div>

Comment: Site is here: https://s.codepen.io/nedhulton/debug/KJEQBO/dGkXWdqVjwoA

Comment: Have you fixed the enter key issue because  i visited the codepen link and paypal modal didn't popup on enter

Comment: It does after Payment is made

Comment: Its embarrassing because somebody makes payment and then when they click enter the box appear again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the blur method to the button in onCancel and onAuthorize processing like so;

```
    onCancel: function(data, actions) {
        $("#paypal-button").blur()
    },

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        $("#paypal-button").blur();
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {

        });
    }
```

This should remove focus from the button after the modal is closed

Comment: Have you checked that it actually gets to that code after the user closes the modal? 
Also, link you provided earlier is expired. Please send another so we can help debug